# Unwanted text motion with box around text enabled

Tags: emacs

EMACS 24.2 To make evident current line I customize hl-line with 1 pixel "box around text" instead of backlight.
When I move cursor, text move (left-right up/down)  +- 2  pixels giving me a sense of nausea. Is there a way to avoid this unwanted text motion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try to use a box of width -1 (that's right, a negative number).

Comment: Hi Stefan, this partially resolves. Vertical flickering disappear but still remains the horizontal one, anyway now it's much more better, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, there shouldn't be such flickering.  So please `M-x report-emacs-bug`